# How can I remove these plastic foundation vents?

Tags: crawlspace

I am trying to figure out how these come out. They appear to be installed upside down. What is holding them in? Terminix advised to replace them at some insane cost, but would rather try myself first!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you see on the inside?

Comment: Do you want to remove and re-install them, or will you be replacing with something new? There's less need to remove with care if they'll be replaced anyway.

Comment: Looks like there's a little lever there, have you tried wiggling that? Have you put a big screwdriver into the notches along the bottom to try to pry there?

Comment: Lever is to open and close them... I am planning to replace them

Comment: You mean the lever opens and closes some louvers which control air flow? Something chewed its way through. I am surprised a rat could chew that steel mesh. Maybe chewed the plastic and then forced aside the galvanized steel "hardware cloth". Do you have the new vents in hand or at least picked out?

Comment: As a frame challenge: one of the vents appears intact, while the other has a hole. Consider cutting a piece of [steel mesh](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.twpinc.com%2Fmedia%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fcache%2Fd6dac3d9f20a0a91c6684a8ce5dd57de%2Fs%2F_%2Fs_s-5_041.jpg&tbnid=0vl2dST4r-QukM&vet=12ahUKEwj744j6xJ-EAxWnO0QIHUQnB_QQMygEegUIARCzAQ..i&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.twpinc.com%2F5-mesh-t304-stainless-041-wire-dia-005x005s0410-disc&docid=2M6zNYjEPBbeKM&w=640&h=480&q=steel%20mesh&ved=2ahUKEwj744j6xJ-EAxWnO0QIHUQnB_QQMygEegUIARCzAQ)(pic from TWC, Inc. via Google Images)...

Comment: ... larger than the hole, then place it over the hole, and secure the mesh to the existing vent screen and grille with half-a-dozen short wire segments. There'd then be no need to R&R the vents.

Comment: cover them with Mosquito net (not fly net)

Comment: It looks to me like the lever is a latching mechanism and they open by swinging out (like awning windows).  A chisel or oscillating multi-tool (with the right blade) could probably get the frame out.  You might try posting a picture with the vents opened to get better suggestions.  Also, please explain whether you want to re-install the same vents or replace with something else.